# Woocommerce - Shop page product listing only certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I'm wanting to only have products from two certain categories listed on the /../shop page. All the rest will need to be searched for or found using buttons I have already on the site.

I've tried a few different code snippets but nothing seems to do what I'm wanting it to.

Any help would be much apprenticed, 
Many Thanks
Lewis

Comment: where is your code. show your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's explained on the WooCommerce Page, you only need to change it to your needs.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/

In your case, change the operator to "IN" and

terms => array('knives')

to

terms => array( 'your-cat-slug-1' , 'your-cat-slug-2' ),

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) { 

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

    $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'your-cat-slug-1' , 'your-cat-slug-2' ), // Display products in the your-cat-slug-1/your-cat-slug-2 category on the shop page
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )));

}

remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Put this Code in your Child-themes functions.php file.

Comment: Little late replying sorry, But I've tested this snippet and I thought It was doing everything I needed it to then realized it was not only allowing listening certain product categories within the /shop page but also only allowing these categories to be displayed within a search. Is there a way to only allow certain categories on the /shop page but searches will still search all products.

Comment: i'm not sure, can't test it now. But maybe if 
( ! is_admin() && ! is_search() && is_shop() ) {
might work.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you wish to show only specific categries on the `/shop` page correct? So use the code below, change product_cat to what you need it to be...

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','shop_filter_cat');

     function shop_filter_cat($query) {
        if (!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && $query->is_main_query()) {
           $query->set('tax_query', array(
                        array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                           'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => 'type-1'
                                     )
                         )
           );   
        }
     }
```